# javascript error return from select

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, select

i can't understand why if i select the second option 'carne' it returns the value of first option.

```
var nodoChiave;
var nodoCerca;
var nodoRisultato;

var ricettario = [
{
    categoria: "primo",
    nome: "pasta",
    difficolta: "media",
    preparazione: 30
},
{
    categoria: "secondo",
    nome: "carne",
    difficolta: "bassa",
    preparazione: 15
}
];

function calcolaListaDescrizioni(ricette) {
try {
    var listaDescrizioni = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ricette.length; i++) {
        var ricetta = ricettario[i];
        var s = "(" + ricetta.categoria + ") " + ricetta.nome + ", difficolta " + ricetta.difficolta + ", minuti di preparazione " + ricetta.preparazione;
        listaDescrizioni.push(s);
    }
    return listaDescrizioni;

} catch (e) {
    alert("calcolaListaDescrizioni" + e);
}
}

function gestoreCerca() {
try {
    var chiave = nodoChiave.value;
    var ricette = ricercaEsatta(chiave);
    var listaDescrizioni;
    if (ricette.length != 0) {
        listaDescrizioni = calcolaListaDescrizioni(ricette);
    } else {
        listaDescrizioni = ["nessuna ricetta trovata"];
    }
    creaLista(nodoRisultato, listaDescrizioni);
} catch(e) {
    alert("gestoreCerca" + e);
}
}

function ricercaEsatta(chiave) {
var listaRicette = [];
var i = 0; 
while( (i < ricettario.length) && (ricettario[i].nome != chiave)) {
    i++;
}
if (i < ricettario.length) {
    listaRicette.push(ricettario[i]);
}
console.log(listaRicette) ;
return listaRicette;
}

function creaLista(nodoLista, elementi) {
rimuoviFigli(nodoLista);
for (var i = 0; i< elementi.length; i++) {
    var elemento = elementi[i];
    var nodoElemento = document.createElement("li");
    nodoLista.appendChild(nodoElemento);
    var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(elemento);
    nodoElemento.appendChild(nodoTesto);
}
}

function rimuoviFigli(nodo) {
while (nodo.childNodes.length > 0) {
    nodo.removeChild(nodo.firstChild);
}
}

function inizializza(){
try {
    nodoChiave = document.getElementById("chiave");
    nodoCerca = document.getElementById("cerca");
    nodoRisultato = document.getElementById("risultato");

    nodoCerca.onclick = gestoreCerca;
} catch(e) {
    alert("inizializza" + e);
}
}

window.onload = inizializza;
```

and the html:

```
<body>
<b> Le mie ricette: </b>
<input type="text" id="chiave">
<input type="button" id="cerca" value="Cerca">
<br>
<br>
<div id="risultato"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

if i search something that is not present in the array it works. 
and, when i select the second option, the console.log() of ricercaMultipla() returns the correct item of the array 'ricettario'.
i'm learning javascript, and it will definitely be stupid, but thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Because in for loop you are accessing `ricettario` instead of `ricette`

change this line

```
 var ricetta = ricettario[i];
```

to

```
var ricetta = ricette[i];
```

```js
var nodoChiave;
var nodoCerca;
var nodoRisultato;

var ricettario = [
{
    categoria: "primo",
    nome: "pasta",
    difficolta: "media",
    preparazione: 30
},
{
    categoria: "secondo",
    nome: "carne",
    difficolta: "bassa",
    preparazione: 15
}
];

function calcolaListaDescrizioni(ricette) {

try {
    var listaDescrizioni = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ricette.length; i++) {
        var ricetta = ricette[i];
        var s = "(" + ricetta.categoria + ") " + ricetta.nome + ", difficolta " + ricetta.difficolta + ", minuti di preparazione " + ricetta.preparazione;
       
        listaDescrizioni.push(s);
    }
    return listaDescrizioni;

} catch (e) {
    alert("calcolaListaDescrizioni" + e);
}
}

function gestoreCerca() {
try {
    var chiave = nodoChiave.value;
    var ricette = ricercaEsatta(chiave);
    var listaDescrizioni;
    if (ricette.length != 0) {
        listaDescrizioni = calcolaListaDescrizioni(ricette);
    } else {
        listaDescrizioni = ["nessuna ricetta trovata"];
    }
    creaLista(nodoRisultato, listaDescrizioni);
} catch(e) {
    alert("gestoreCerca" + e);
}
}

function ricercaEsatta(chiave) {
var listaRicette = [];
var i = 0; 
while( (i < ricettario.length) && (ricettario[i].nome != chiave)) {
    ++i;
}
if (i < ricettario.length) {
    listaRicette.push(ricettario[i]);
}
console.log(listaRicette) ;
return listaRicette;
}

function creaLista(nodoLista, elementi) {
rimuoviFigli(nodoLista);
for (var i = 0; i< elementi.length; i++) {
    var elemento = elementi[i];
    var nodoElemento = document.createElement("li");
    nodoLista.appendChild(nodoElemento);
    var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(elemento);
    nodoElemento.appendChild(nodoTesto);
}
}

function rimuoviFigli(nodo) {
while (nodo.childNodes.length > 0) {
    nodo.removeChild(nodo.firstChild);
}
}

function inizializza(){
try {
    nodoChiave = document.getElementById("chiave");
    nodoCerca = document.getElementById("cerca");
    nodoRisultato = document.getElementById("risultato");

    nodoCerca.onclick = gestoreCerca;
} catch(e) {
    alert("inizializza" + e);
}
}

window.onload = inizializza;
```

```html
<body>
<b> Le mie ricette: </b>
<input type="text" id="chiave">
<input type="button" id="cerca" value="Cerca">
<br>
<br>
<div id="risultato"></div>
</body>
</html>
```